# Movie where two or three men playing with a dead body

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I'm looking for a comedy movie where two(or three??) men using the dead body of a man, possibly their boss to hide the fact that he's dead and trying to find out how he is dead?

From what I recall, the dead man is a very rich businessman who is killed by his business partner/friend. The event happens at a beach house or place like that. The rich man just bought the house and an evening party was being held there.

I think he is killed during the party by injecting some poison into his body by a brutal assassin. The main characters play many pranks with the dead body to avoid others from knowing the fact that he's dead.

I think the timeline of the movie is between late 90's and early 2000's..

Comment: @Paulster2 check before approving an edit. Its an invalid edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Weekend at Bernie's](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098627/) probably, but it's been awhile.

> A pair of losers try to pretend that their murdered employer is really alive, but the murderer is out to "finish him off."

Comment: @anem ator, On the one hand, I'm disappointed that you beat me to answering this. I knew the answer as soon as a read the title of the question. On the other hand, I'm glad to see I'm not the only one who's ever seen this movie.

Comment: @RKN, You should also check out the sequel to the movie, [Weekend at Bernie's II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108539/). In the sequel, Bernie's body is stolen from the morgue, and a voodoo ritual is performed on him to make him walk to where he hid the money he stole from the company.